# Version file in only one branch and but keep in workspace/.gitignore in others

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

I have about five local branches.  There is a locally used utility script that I would like to use in all of those branches, however, I want to version it in only one of them (let's call it **BranchX**) and ignore it in the rest.

The problem is, when I commit the script to BranchX and check out another branch, the script disappears because it is properly versioned in another branch (BranchX) but neither committed into the current branch nor ignored in it.  So I have a feeling I need to do something when I am in BranchX to tell git to, although the file is versioned there, always keep it on disk even when I go to a different branch so that I can add it to its `.gitignore` (unless it is there already).

I was thinking of `git rm --cached <PATH>` which I have used before to remove a versioned file from a local branch but keep it on disk, however, I do not want to remove it from that git branch and that is what this command will do for me.  How do I accomplish the same thing that command does minus the remove from versioning so the file can wait for me there on disk when I switch to another branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git-submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). You can keep your script under versioning in a separated `repo` and use it as a dependency in your main repo, making it avaible in all your branches.